# xsl for iteration and do addition

Tags: xml, xslt

Input:

```
<root><element>
  <small>a</small>
  <Large>B</Large>
  <Time>301</Time></element><element>
  <small>a</small>
  <Large>B</Large>
  <Time>322</Time></element><element>
  <small>b</small>
  <Large>A</Large>
  <Time>274</Time></element><element>
  <small>c</small>
  <Large>B</Large>
  <Time>325</Time></element><element>
  <small>b</small>
  <Large>A</Large>
  <Time>301</Time></element></root>
```

Need to write a xslt see how many times the small and Large elements comes in pair and list the count in smallnum tag and also add the time of that many iterations to totsmalltime tag.

Output:

```
<root><element>
  <small>a</small>
  <Large>B</Large>
  <smallnum>2</smallnum>
  <totsmalltime>623</totsmalltime></element><element>
  <small>b</small>
  <Large>A</Large>
  <smallnum>2</smallnum>
  <totsmalltime>575</totsmalltime></element><element>
  <small>c</small>
  <Large>B</Large>
  <smallnum>1</smallnum>
  <totsmalltime>325</totsmalltime></element></root>
```

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT2.0 or just XSLT1.0?

Comment: It's not clear enough what you're asking.  What is `smallnum` supposed to count?  What is `totsmalltime` supposed to cumulate?

Comment: @harpo smallnum supposed to count hou many times the combination of small-Large combination happend  and totsmalltime is the sum of time tag of that many iterations

Comment: @TimC XSLT 1.0 only but it would be great if you also provide solution in XSLT2.0 for future use

Comment: I've expanded my answer to show an XSLT2.0 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

**Here is a shorter solution that is completely "push style" :)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElem" match="element"
  use="concat(small, '+', Large)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "element[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kElem',concat(small, '+', Large))[1])]">
  <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select="key('kElem',concat(small, '+', Large))"/>

  <element>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   <smallnum><xsl:value-of select="count($vGroup)"/></smallnum>
   <totsmalltime><xsl:value-of select="sum($vGroup/Time)"/></totsmalltime>
  </element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="element|Time"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <element>
        <small>a</small>
        <Large>B</Large>
        <Time>301</Time>
    </element>
    <element>
        <small>a</small>
        <Large>B</Large>
        <Time>322</Time>
    </element>
    <element>
        <small>b</small>
        <Large>A</Large>
        <Time>274</Time>
    </element>
    <element>
        <small>c</small>
        <Large>B</Large>
        <Time>325</Time>
    </element>
    <element>
        <small>b</small>
        <Large>A</Large>
        <Time>301</Time>
    </element>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <element>
      <small>a</small>
      <Large>B</Large>
      <smallnum>2</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>623</totsmalltime>
   </element>
   <element>
      <small>b</small>
      <Large>A</Large>
      <smallnum>2</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>575</totsmalltime>
   </element>
   <element>
      <small>c</small>
      <Large>B</Large>
      <smallnum>1</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>325</totsmalltime>
   </element>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. Proper use of the **[Muenchian Grouping Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <root>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="concat(small, '+', Large)">
    <element>
     <xsl:sequence select="small, Large"/>
     <smallnum>
       <xsl:sequence select="count(current-group())"/>
     </smallnum>
     <totsmalltime>
      <xsl:sequence select="sum(current-group()/Time)"/>
     </totsmalltime>
    </element>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <element>
      <small>a</small>
      <Large>B</Large>
      <smallnum>2</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>623</totsmalltime>
   </element>
   <element>
      <small>b</small>
      <Large>A</Large>
      <smallnum>2</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>575</totsmalltime>
   </element>
   <element>
      <small>c</small>
      <Large>B</Large>
      <smallnum>1</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>325</totsmalltime>
   </element>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of **[`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-for-each-group)** with `group-by` attribute.
2. Proper use of the **[`current-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-current-group)** function.

Comment: Could you please explain this line      <xsl:template match=
 "element[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kElem',concat(small, '+', Large))[1])]">

Comment: @mnvbrtn, \This answer provides a link for the Muenchian Gouping -- just click it. The template matches any element that is the first (in document order) having the key `concat(`small, '+', Large)` for the key named `kElem`. The function `concat()` is used to specify a composite key. The delimiter `"+"` is used to disambiguate the concatenation of strings for example how do we know whether "predefined" is the result of concatenating "pre" and "defined" and not "prede" and "fined".

Answer (score 2):

To do this in XSLT1.0 you would use Muenchian Grouping. In your case you are grouping **Time** elements by a combination of the first preceding **Large** and **small** elements. This means you would start by defining the following key

```
<xsl:key 
   name="pairs" 
   match="Time" 
   use="concat(preceding-sibling::Large[1], '|', preceding-sibling::small[1])" />
```

Then, you would need to the **Time** elements that appear first in the group for their specific key. You would do this as follows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
  select="element/Time[
     generate-id()
     = generate-id(
         key(
           'pairs', 
           concat(preceding-sibling::Large[1], '|', preceding-sibling::small[1])
          )[1])]" />
```

Then, for example, to get the **smallnum** value, which is the value of all the elements in the group, you would simply do this, where **$key** is defined as`concat(preceding-sibling::Large[1], '|', preceding-sibling::small[1])`

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('pairs', $key))" />
```

For the **totsmalltime** element, just use sum instead of count.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="pairs" match="Time" use="concat(preceding-sibling::Large[1], '|', preceding-sibling::small[1])"/>

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="element/Time[generate-id() = generate-id(key('pairs', concat(preceding-sibling::Large[1], '|', preceding-sibling::small[1]))[1])]"/>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Time">
      <xsl:variable name="small" select="preceding-sibling::small[1]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="Large" select="preceding-sibling::Large[1]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="key" select="concat($Large, '|', $small)"/>
      <element>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$small"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$Large"/>
         <smallnum>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(key('pairs', $key))"/>
         </smallnum>
         <totsmalltime>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('pairs', $key))"/>
         </totsmalltime>
      </element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<root>
   <element>
      <small>a</small>
      <Large>B</Large>
      <smallnum>2</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>623</totsmalltime>
   </element>
   <element>
      <small>b</small>
      <Large>A</Large>
      <smallnum>2</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>575</totsmalltime>
   </element>
   <element>
      <small>c</small>
      <Large>B</Large>
      <smallnum>1</smallnum>
      <totsmalltime>325</totsmalltime>
   </element>
</root>
```

EDIT: In XSLT2.0 you could make use of the **xsl:for-each-group** element, together with **current-group()** when doing the count and sum.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <root>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="element/Time" group-by="concat(preceding-sibling::Large[1], '|', preceding-sibling::small[1])">
            <element>
               <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::small[1]"/>
               <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::Large[1]"/>
               <smallnum>
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
               </smallnum>
               <totsmalltime>
                  <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group())"/>
               </totsmalltime>
            </element>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should also output the same XML.

Comment: My solution is over-complicated, as I failed to spot the fact the Large and small nodes are nested with an element node.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you're after is called *Muenchian grouping*, you want to group your `element` elements by a combination of their `small` and `Large` values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="smallLarge" match="element"
        use="concat(small, '_', Large)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element[generate-id() = generate-id(
             key('smallLarge', concat(small, '_', Large)[1])]" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <element>
      <small><xsl:value-of select="small" /></small>
      <Large><xsl:value-of select="Large" /></Large>
      <smallnum><xsl:value-of select="count(key('smallLarge',
                  concat(small, '_', Large)))" /></smallnum>
      <totsmalltime><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('smallLarge',
                  concat(small, '_', Large))/Time)" /></totsmalltime>
    </element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The interesting line is

```
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/element[generate-id() = generate-id(
             key('smallLarge', concat(small, '_', Large)[1])]" />
```

which uses `generate-id` to select only the *first* `element` element for each key value.  Therefore the `element` template will be called once for each `small`/`Large` combination, and that template can use the key to count and sum up all the times for that particular key value.

P.S. the indentation on your original XML example is terrible, it took me several readings to notice the `element` elements, at first it looked like one long sequence of `small`, `Large` and `Time` siblings...